# Changing Materials On Multiple Copies Of Same Object (within cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is there a way with the material compositor to make it so that when I have multiple objects (duplicated) within a scene that their materials change just because of the simple fact that they are duplicated?

EG. I have 2000 AirSoft pellets in this scene (some are duplicated for precise positions, others are within a particle system. But all use the same exact material), I don't want them all to be red, I want them to be either of the three colors; red,blue,purple.

I want to also choose that a majority are red (50%) and blue & purple would be 25% each. So 1,000 red and 500 blue and 500 purple.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *Random* output of the object info node to get random values between 1 and 0 that are unique to each object with the material. You can use this to change the color of an object using a color ramp node:

[image]

However, this only works for objects (you convert your particle system to objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Make Duplicates Real*, but they will no longer be animated).

You can kind of do the same thing for particles with the *index* output of the *Particle info* node (dividing it by the number of particles), however the output will not be random; the first particle will have a value of 0 and the last will have a value of 1.

If your particles move around and get mixed up enough, it may not be noticeable, especially if you chop up the color ramp node:

[image]

Comment: You might also add more variation by sending the divided values through some high-frequency sin / cos math nodes.

Comment: @maddin45 Hmm.. I couldn't get that to work, perhaps I did something wrong . . .

Comment: Try [this setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfR7y.png). The "high frequency" is actually acieved by multiplying the particle index by a large random value.

Comment: That setting is for the particle simulator as well, maddin?

Comment: @John It is especially for the particles, since it only uses the particle index and not a random value. You could probably add a random input as well, but I don't know how the particle info node behaves when no particle system is present.